# mp4 and webm causes conflicts in web browsers when using videojs

Tags: javascript, html, video, webm

I use the video player **videojs** below :

```
<video id="font_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="700" height="360" poster="" data-setup="{}">
  <source src="xxx.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  <source src="xxx.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>

<script>
   _V_.options.flash.swf = "assets/video-js.swf";
</script>
```

The above code successfully runs in **Safari**,but doesn't run in **Chrome** and **Firefox**.

If I swap the *mp4* and *webm* position, like this:

```
<video id="font_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="700" height="360" poster="" data-setup="{}">
  <source src="xxx.webm" type='video/webm' />
  <source src="xxx.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Then the code doesn't run in **Safari** anymore, but runs in **Chrome** and **Firefox**.
Does anybody have an explanation ?

Comment: are you sure just by changing the positions the video is working in chrome and firefox? . Which version of safari are you using?

Comment: have you checked that each video will play in Chrome and Safari without VideoJS in the picture, just a regular `<video>` tag with one video

Comment: @karthick Yes.My safari version is 6.0.3.I edit my problem, I think videojs must play the first <source>.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal I use jplayer can play the video in the chrome and safari.I edit my problem, I think videojs must play the first <source>.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal When I delete the `<source src="xxx.webm" type='video/webm />`, Safari can play and Chrome can not.When I delete `<source src="xxx.mp4" type='video/mp4' />`, Safari can not play and Chrome can.

Comment: The VideoJS docs imply it should be fine. Do you have pointers to a sample page with real videos we can check (I'm wondering if there's a MIME type or encoding issue that's breaking things)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Thanks, I am changing the positions the video can solve this problem. The webm video must at the first source. You can post your answer, I will select your answer.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that the encoding of the mp4 is not quite right so when Chrome tries to play it it fails but doesn't fall through to the WebM version either

Comment: But why safari can play the mp4？